# AlarmManager Set Specific Time Execution

Tags: java, android, date, time, alarmmanager

I was having some problem when trying to set specific time to execute the AlarmManager. Here is the code where I schedule my Alarm:

```
public static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {
    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;

    notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

I am trying to set the alarm manager to run at 0030 if it meets the conditions in my if statement. However, the alarmManager will not send push-notification although some records did met the requirements. So I changed the codes to repeat every 2 minutes by:

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.getTimeInMillis(),
            2*60*60, pi);
```

And it did send the push-notifications correctly. I wonder what's the mistake I made for the part when I tried to specified a time for it to execute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if current day's time 00:30 already passed? It would never work....

Comment: @Salmaan I thought you can change the phone's date time?